# How to check an element's existence after a loading animation in a UI Test? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

The problem is simple: How to check an element's existence after a loading animation in a UI Test? BUT without using static timeouts.

For example: If animation lasts 3 seconds ui test waits for 3 seconds, if animation lasts 10 seconds ui test waits for 10 seconds or is there another way around it?

I'm trying to wait as long as my api call lasts simply

Answer (score 2):

You can tackle this in one of two two ways: 1) Wait for your element to exist or 2) Wait for the animation to disappear.

In order to wait for your element to exist, you'd use Apple's [waitForExistence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence) function with a long timeout on your target element. This returns a boolean so you can simply assert directly on it.

```
XCTAssertTrue(myElement.waitForExistence(timeout: 15.0)) // wait for 15 seconds maximum
```

In order to wait for your animation to disappear, you'd identify it, and extend XCUIElement with the following function, which I use extensively and therefore bundle into my [XCToolbox Cocoapod](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence). You'd then be able to check the `exists` property on your target element.

```
public func waitForDisappearance(timeout: TimeInterval = Waits.short.rawValue) -> Bool {
    let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: NSPredicate(format: UIStatus.notExist.rawValue), object: self)
    let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: timeout)
    switch result {
    case .completed:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

This code would look like the following:

```
_ = animationElement.waitForDisappearance(timeout: 15.0)
XCTAssertTrue(myElement.exists)
```

Neither solution is wrong. The first is less code and arguably cleaner, the second is more explicit and *possibly* more readable.

Comment: The whole idea was to set the timeout dynamically but I don't see any dynamic timeout in here. Am I wrong?

Comment: Both are dynamic. If they find what they’re looking for prior to your timeout they will complete immediately.  They only “fail” (return false) when they reach the timeout without satisfying your expectation.